# How to do a wiredump of XMLRPC::Client in ruby?

Tags: xml, ruby, xml-rpc

I'm working on some code using XML RPC in ruby and need to see some debug info, how do you do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reading the source of the package, XMLRPC::Client uses Net::HTTP in turn as its transport.

So I think you should be able to monkey-patch a method into the XMLRPC::Client accordingly:

```
require 'pp'

# the magic happens here
class XMLRPC::Client
  def set_debug
    @http.set_debug_output($stderr);
  end
end

server = XMLRPC::Client.new2("http://rpc.technorati.com/rpc/ping")
server.set_debug
result = server.call("weblogUpdates.ping", "Copenhagen.rb", "http://www.copenhagenrb.dk/")
pp result
```

(sample for XMLRPC snarfed from [here](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2597)).

Answer (score 0):

Fine answer here, but do note that the http-level dump may often be gzip encoded and thus not very good for debugging through. Another option is to use `client.http_last_response`. E.g.:

```
server = XMLRPC::Client.new2("http://rpc.technorati.com/rpc/ping")
result = server.call("weblogUpdates.ping", "Copenhagen.rb", "http://www.copenhagenrb.dk/")
puts server.http_last_response.body
```